# How to secure my windows 7 WiFi internet shared(hotspot)?

Tags: security, networking, wireless-networking

I turned my laptop into Hotspot and am sure you understand this. So now I have problem with WPA2-personal that can't be connected by some devices like Iphone. lets leave this. Now I want to either find a way to make my WEP more secure by letting my windows accept preferred devices by assigning ip address or getting MAC address of the preferred devices. Or is there any software that can manage those security issue for me that I can use it as a manager on my laptop? or any other suggestion?

Note: Please don't mention Connectify-me to me I am definitely aware of that software and my  purpose is quite far from using that software. I want a solution for the problem I mentioned.

Thank you so much for all.

Comment: Don't use WEP. iPhones should have no problem with WPA2. Oh, and this isn't a programming question.

Comment: This question would be better placed on SuperUser and not here.

Answer (score 0):

Anything less than WPA2 is insecure, and can be cracked given enough time.  Even the most secure WEP key can be brute forced in a matter of minutes if the attacker is able to capture enough IV frames (which he can trigger through various techniques).  The technical aspects of the cracking far exceed the scope of this answer, but if you want to learn more I recommend the [BackTrack 5 Wireless Penetration Testing Beginner's Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849515581).

There are no modern devices to my knowledge that do not support WPA2.  My brother-in-law has an iPhone that works fine with my WPA2 router.  I think you should focus your troubleshooting efforts on the devices rather than your laptop.  Whatever you do, resist the temptation to go with WEP.  If you do, you will get hacked.